780x thermal protection circuitry
The venerable 780x family of regulators have their own internal thermal protection circuitry. I have the following questions

Which transistor(s) (or possibly other components) are responsible for the detection of an overheat situation and the ultimate restriction on the output current?

How does the over-heat protection circuitry work?


Here is a schematic taken from OnSemi:

I am guessing that the circuitry of interest might include Q14 and Q1, because their collectors are tied together, and their bases as well, and one has a 1 kΩ emitter resistor (R6) while the other has a 14 kΩ emitter (R7). Thus, their Vbe's are likely to vary between them in a temperature dependent way. However, if that is so, I am somewhat at a loss to explain a) the presence or purpose of Q13 and the reason for the double emitter of Q1. Perhaps the double emitter is used to "and" (merge) in another overload condition, similar to the way a double emitter is used in TTL NAND gates. Any insights will be appreciated.

According to Ken Shirriff's blog post on reverse-engineering ST's 7805, it's transistor Q8 in your chip, but can't answer the details.

Now that is an interesting blog https://www.righto.com/2014/09/reverse-engineering-counterfeit-7805.html. Strangely, I don't see a double emitter transistor anywhere in the schematic there, so I'm wondering if OnSemi's chip is different from ST's. Also, I think sometimes the part schematics in datasheets are not "exact" matches for the manufactured part. I need to look at the new schematic more carefully.

Looks like Q8 is held at constant bias with no emitter degeneration, allowing the collector current to "steal" some of the error signal from the Q19/Q20 output stage as its current gain rises with temperature. From the interactive die shot on Ken Schrriff's blog, you can see that, despite its placement on the schematic, Q8 (Q13 on his schematic) is right next to the R16/Q16 (again, as annotated on his schematic) output components.


It is Q8. Diode D1 and Q7 combine to provide a voltage reference at a zero to a bit positive TC, depending on the actual zener voltage.
That puts the base of Q8 at a 'fixed voltage'.  Since Q8 Vbe has a negative TC, at some 'high' temperature, Q8 will turn on, shunting the bias current from Q18 to it, instead of Q19 base, pulling the Q19 base node down, de-biasing the output stage, shutting the regulator off.
To your other questions, Q14, Q1 and Q13 are the reference circuit.  Q14 and Q1 generate the delta Vbe part of the reference.  Since Q14 and Q1 are set up as emitter followers, Q13 provides the gain necessary to regulate this loop. A diode-based CMOS reference is quite similar to this.
